# Ito Integral Properties with Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am working out some of the properties for the Ito integral with Brownian motion and I am trying to use the definition to verify that 
 $$ \int _0 ^t s \, dB_s = tB_t - \int _0 ^t B_s\, ds $$
and

$$ \int _0 ^t B_s^2 \, dB_s = \frac{1}{3}(B_t^3) - \int _0 ^t B_s\, ds $$

I am having trouble thinking about how to attack this so any help or suggestions on how to get started would be great!

Comment: I'm confused: if you subtract your two equations you get: $B_t^2/3 = tB_t$.

Comment: sorry typo, should be $$ B_t^3 $$. ill fix now

Comment: it still doesn't look right.

Comment: Really sorry for the typos.  I am new to uses latex type text.  I have verified that it is now fully correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED to meet edit of question

The first equation is (after the edit) true.
 Consider the twodimensional continuous semimartingale $\left( t,B_t\right)$, and function $f(x,y)=xy$
we get $$D_xf(x,y)=y\quad D_yf(x,y)=x\quad D_1D_1f=D_2D_2f=0\quad D_1D_2f=D_2D_1f=1$$
And therefore ITO's formula gives
$$tB_t=0+\int_0^t s\; dB_s+\int_0^t B_s\; ds.$$

The 2nd equation is (after the edit) true as well. You can convince yourself with an argument similar to the one i gave.  Apply the 1-dimensional ITO's formula on $B_t$ with $f(x)=x^3$

Comment: Sorry! thank you for your answer.  I have fixed the typos in the original question.

Comment: @user3692250 No problem. If you have further questions on this topic, write them in the comments.  If you do not, mark the answer as an answer.

Comment: I understand your solution but do you know how to prove those properties from a general standpoint?  Maybe just using the definition of the Ito integral.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can prove these equalities only using the definition of the Ito integral. Well in some sense you can: derive Ito's formula from the definition of the Ito integral, then use it.

Comment: Yes, I have realized that you have to use Ito's formula in some way so the above answer is correct.  thanks!